# how to delete an empty array from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

i need a function to delete an array which include an empty element from multidimensional array in php suppose following is my array here i need to find out and delete array[1] and array[2] since element empty has no value.

```
$array[] = array(
   'name'=>'name1',
   'email'=>'email1',
   'empty'=>'NOT_EMPTY'
);
$array[] = array(
   'name'=>'name2',
   'email'=>'email2',
   'empty'=>''
);
$array[] = array(
   'name'=>'',
   'email'=>'',
   'empty'=>''
);
```

when i do

```
$array = array_map('array_filter', $array);

print_r($array);
```

i got the result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1
            [email] => email1
            [empty]=> NOT_EMPTY
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2
            [email] => email2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

BUT EXPECTED RESULT

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2
            [email] => email2
            [empty]=> NOT_EMPTY
        )

)
```

Comment: We'll also need to see your `array_filter()` function code to understand how you're getting the results.

Comment: it is an inbuilt function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter()` on its own only `unset`s values that equate to false, not the entire array. you will need to loop, and if any array has missing element, then unset array, like:

```
foreach($array as $key => $a){
  if(count(array_filter($a)) < count($a)){
    unset($array[$key]);
  }
}
```

there probably is a better way, i'm just simple